# How to set multiple data in JCo Table using RFC?

Tags: java, servlets, jco

I want to add multiple data in my JCo Table using RFC to SAP server.

Below is my Code.

**But problem is only last raw will be set to sap.**

What I am missing?

I am using one function for sync data with SAP.

```
JCO.Function function = null;
JCO.Repository mRepository;

public String updateCustomerToSAP(String bapi){

    String message = null;
    Connection conn = new Connection();
    JCO.client mConnection = conn.open();
    JCO.Table GETZPRTL_VISIT = null;
    mConnection.connect();
    
    try{
        function = this.createFunction(bapi);
        if(function == null){
            // Not fount
        }else{
            GETZPRTL_VISIT = function.getTableParameterList().getTable("CUSTOMER_VISIT");
            
            for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++){
                GETZPRTL_VISIT.appendRow();
                GETZPRTL_VISIT.setValue("0001 "+i,"ID");
                GETZPRTL_VISIT.setValue("john_ro "+i,"USER_NAME");
                GETZPRTL_VISIT.setValue("John "+i,"FIRST_NAME");
                GETZPRTL_VISIT.setValue("Martin "+i,"LAST_NAME");
                GETZPRTL_VISIT.setValue("john.martin@gmail.com "+i,"EMAIL");
            }
            
            // Above data is just for and example. I fetch those data from ArrayList and all data are diffrent.
        
            function.getImportParameterList().setValue("Data1","USER_ID");
            function.getImportParameterList().setValue("type goes here","TYPE");
            function.getImportParameterList().setValue("reason goes here","REASON");
            function.getImportParameterList().setValue("final status","STATUS");
            function.getImportParameterList().setValue("0001","NUMBER");
        
            mConnection.execute(function);
            message = (String) function.getExportParameterList().getValue("MESSAGE");
        
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
    
    }
    conn.disconnect();
    
    return message;
} 

public JCO.Function createFunction(String name) throws Exception{
    try{
        IFunctionTamplate ft = mRepository.getFunctionTamplate(name.toUpperCase());
        
        if(ft == null)
            return null;
        return ft.getFunction();
        
    }catch(Exception e){
        throw new Exception("Problem retriving JCO.Function object"+ e);
    }
}
```

Here **CUSTOMER_VISIT** is **Table** which is inside of my RFC.

**Structure Example**

```
USER_ID
TYPE
REASON
STATUS
NUMBER
CUSTOMER_VISIT    <= This is Table inside function module.
```

**CUSTOMER_VISIT** Table Structure

```
ID
USER_NAME
FIRST_NAME
LAST_NAME
EMAIL
```

Comment: if your code sample is complete and unchanged, the table referenced by  GETZPRTL_VISIT would contain 10 rows, all identical. Is it possible there is some kind of filtering on the function module side going on? Table CUSTOMER_VISIT is a table parameter of the function module, not just a structure?

Comment: CUSTOMER_VISIT is table in side function module.

Comment: Everything  working fine if there is only one record. But if there is more than 2 record, it store only last one.

Comment: have you verified that only one record is actually sent to the SAP system? I can't find anything wrong with your code and the question would be if the problem lies within the function module. You could test the function module within the SAP system without having to call it from a JCo connection.

Comment: I test my function module with in SAP system. First I add 3 row of data in Table(CUSTOMER_VISIT) after fill other data (USER_ID, TYPE, REASON, STATUS and NUMBER). And click on Execute. This will run properly. It will save all 3 row in table.

Comment: one other problem I can see is that setValue() seems to expect the column name first, then the value. You call setValue() with the value first, then the column. Maybe that is just in your sample code. To be honest, at this point I'd step into the debugger and see what may be wrong with your code. Check if the table parameter really contains several rows or if there is some other problem in the application logic.

Comment: I tried to add column name first and value as second parameter, But this gives me and error JCO_ERROR_FIELD_NOT_FOUND : field 024687 is not a member of VISIT_REPORT.

Comment: looks like you're right, setvalue() has several overloads and the (string,string) variant needs value first, then column name: https://help.sap.com/javadocs/NW04/current/jc/com/sap/mw/jco/JCO.Record.html#setValue(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String).

Comment: I also tried this way also.

`ParameterList parameterList = function.getTableParameterList();
table.appendRow();
table.setValue("Value","COLUMN");
parameterList.setValue(table,"VISIT_REPORT");
function.setTableParameterList(parameterList);`

But no success. Only Last raw saved in.

Comment: @DirkTrilsbeek JCo 2 expected the value first and the name of the field second in `setValue(String, String)` while it is vice versa with JCo 3. Brings a lot of fun if you have to migrate from the former to the latter.

Comment: @Lothar sounds like someone at SAP really hates their customers ;)

Comment: @ChiragSavsani Your code misses the retrieval of the repository. If the code you provided is the actual one, `createFunction` should end up with a `NullPointerException` because `mRepository` is `null`, You create a new connection each time you call `updateCustomerToSAP`. If you retrieved the repsository from an older connection, the repository and the connection no longer "fit" together, leading to problems. The way you fill the table parameter is OK.

Comment: @DirkTrilsbeek Don't get me started on this...

Comment: "one other problem I can see is that setValue() seems to expect the column name first, then the value." -- No, in JCo2 it was indeed "value first, column name second"... Very strange indeed... SAP fixed this with JCo3. But in this example obviously JCo2 is still used.

Answer (score 0):

Can it be the problem is in the ABAP code of the function module? People not familiar with ABAP can easily confuse the "header line of a table" with the "table itself"...

Could it be possible that only the header line is inserted into the database?

You can see, what data JCo sends to R/3, if you activate the JCo trace level. You could also set an external breakpoint on ABAP side and then step through the function module to see first hand, what data it got.